# Using VARCHAR in MySQL for everything! (on small or micro sites)

Tags: php, mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I tried searching for this as I felt it would be a commonly asked beginner's question, but I could only find things that *nearly* answered it.

We have a small PHP app that is at most used by 5 people (total, ever) and maybe 2 simultaneously, so scalability isn't a concern.

However, I still like to do things in a best practice manner, otherwise bad habits form into permanent bad habits and spill into code you write that faces more than just 5 people.

Given this context, my question is: is there any strong reason to use anything other than VARCHAR(250+) in MySQL for a small PHP app that is constantly evolving/changing? If I picked INT but that later needed to include characters, it would be annoying to have to go back and change it when I could have just future-proofed it and made it a VARCHAR to begin with. In other words, choosing anything other than VARCHAR with a large character count seems pointlessly limiting for a small app. Is this correct?

Thanks for reading and possibly answering!

Comment: I don't really understand your example to justify the use of VARCHAR everywhere. If the purpose of the column is clear and its contents should be *numbers* rather than some numerical *codes*, why would you want it to be VARCHAR? Why would you expect the column to store something else? Maybe I just can't see what kind of a small project you are talking about that could evolve so much as to change the purpose of a column to such an extent.

Comment: The time it takes to develop something is insignificant compared to the time that application will live and the maintenance it will require. Do it right the first time across the board

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the major drawbacks will be that you will have to add consistency checks in your code.  For a small, private database, no problem. But for larger projects...

Using the proper types will do a lot of checks automatically. E.g., are there any wrong characters in the value; is the date valid...

As a bonus, it is easy to add extra constraints when using right types; is the age less than 110; is the start date less than the end date; is the indexing an existing value in another table?

I prefer to make the types as specific as possible.  Although server errors can be nasty and hard to debug, it is way better than having a database that is not consistent.

Answer (score 10):

If you have the numbers 1 through 12 in `VARCHAR`, and you need them in numerical order, you get 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.  Is that OK?  Well, you *could* fix it in SQL by saying `ORDER BY col+0`.  Do you like that kludge?

Comment: Thanks, I found that to be an interesting "gotcha" about VARCHAR vs INT. Never even considered that to be a potential problem!

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a great idea to make a habit out of it as with any real amount of data will become inefficient. If you use the text type the amount of storage space used for the same amount of data will be differ depending on your storage engine.

If you do as you suggested don't forget that all values that would normally be of a numeric type will need to be converted to a numeric type in PHP. For example if you store the value "123" as a varchar or text type and retrieve it as $someVar you will have to do:

```
$someVar = intval($someVar);
```

in PHP before arithmetic operations can be performed, otherwise PHP will assume that 123 is a string.

Answer (score -3):

As you may already know VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. We have the advantage of dynamic memory allocation when using VARCHAR.

VARCHAR is stored inline with the table which makes faster when the size is reasonable.

If your app need performance you can go with CHAR which is little faster than VARCHAR.

Comment: CHAR, when it takes more space than VARCHAR, hurts performance because of the extra bulk.

Comment: Hard to choose which comment to flag as the one that answered my question but this one did it for me. Thanks.